# Arcgis Runtime .NET for WPF scene with elevation source shows flat instead

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I tried the Arcgis tutorial from [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/guide/build-a-new-scene.htm). It shows how to add basemap and elevation so that the scene would show a 3D surrounding, but it doesn't. Can someone help me?

This is my .cs file

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Create a new scene
        var myScene = new Scene(Basemap.CreateTopographic());
        Map3D.Scene = myScene;


        // create an elevation source
        var elevationSource = new ArcGISTiledElevationSource(new System.Uri("http://elevation3d.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D/ImageServer"));
        // create a surface and add the elevation surface
        var sceneSurface = new Surface();
        sceneSurface.ElevationSources.Add(elevationSource);

        // apply the surface to the scene
        Map3D.Scene.BaseSurface = sceneSurface;

        // Create camera with an initial camera position (Mount Everest in the Alps mountains)
        var snowdonCamera = new Camera(53.06, -4.04, 1289, 295, 71, 0);

        // Set the scene view's camera position
        Map3D.SetViewpointCameraAsync(snowdonCamera);
    }
```

And this is my xaml file

```
<Grid>
    <esri:SceneView x:Name="Map3D"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: Your code looks fine, and it worked for me (using v100.7 on .NET Core 3.1).
Could you try and run Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) and check that it's actually requesting data from that elevation endpoint and data is successfully coming through?

Comment: @dotMorten thank you so much for this! It was because of I was connected to corporate VPN. I disconnected from it, run the app again and the elevation layer is now loaded. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the corporate VPN I was connected to. For some reason the elevation layer link was blocked by the VPN. I can either set a proxy, or just diconnect from the VPN.